# Overflow problem inside of row. Fittedbox not worked

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Row inside that 4 other Rows and inside of the rows one icon and text.
but when the text increases. I got the overflow problem.

I tried FittedBox and Flexible with fit property equal to FlexFit.loose not worked. 
[image]

this is my code

```
Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.star, color: Color(0xFFf0b649)),
                                Text(
                                  "4.2",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                                Text(
                                  "145",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.people),
                                Text(
                                  "14766768675",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                Text(
                                  "دنبال کردن",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Try wrapping the text widget with a column.
If that doesn't work check this discussion [enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4128). 
I am quite sure that you find your answer there if the column wrap doesn't help. GL :)

Answer (score 0):

try [Wrap()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget

A Wrap lays out each child and attempts to place the child adjacent to the previous child in the main axis, given by direction, leaving spacing space in between. If there is not enough space to fit the child, Wrap creates a new run adjacent to the existing children in the cross axis.